# How to attach a word before each request in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have got a spring mvc controller which has many methods.
In all the methods I start the path by `/api` followed by the actual word.
Currently I have to manually type `/api/request1` `/api/request2` and so on. Is there a way to only mention my request name and `/api` gets appended automatically?
Controller:

```
package com.json.host;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Test {
    @GetMapping(value="/api/host")
    public String returnText() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `@GetMapping(value="/host")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `@RequestMapping("/api")` on class level and omit it on method level then.

So something like this should do the trick:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Test {
    @GetMapping(value="/host")
    public String returnText() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Documented also in javadoc:

> Supported at the type level as well as at the method level! When used
>   at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this primary
>   mapping, narrowing it for a specific handler method.

(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `@RequestMapping("/api")` at class level and in your methods mapping have only the rest of the url.

```
package com.json.host;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Test {
    @GetMapping(value="/host")
    public String returnText() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @RequestMapping(value = "/api") at the class level. it's appended to method level requests automatically.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class Test {

    @GetMapping(value="/request1")
    public String returnText() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/request2")
    public String returnText2() {
        return "hello2";
    }
}
```